# Intellij Idea add Scala support to existing Java project

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea add Scala support to existing Java project.
Just cannot figure it out How to add Scala worksheet to existing Java project?
It would be just nice to have Scala REPL or worksheet.
But after resiarsh and trying I failed to do that.

Answer (score 13):

> To add Scala support to existing module:
>
> 1. Right-click the module in Project View, choose “Add Framework Support…”
> 2. Check “Scala” in technologies list (unavailable if module has Scala facet attached)
> 3. Provide a path to Scala installation (if not detected)

From http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/.